# Welche Wortarten gibt es im Deutschen?

Tags: word-usage

Ich habe mal gehört, im Deutschen gäbe es 10 Wortarten. z.B. hier: [Wortarten auf nachhilfe-team.net](https://www.nachhilfe-team.net/lernen-leicht-gemacht/wortarten-uebersicht/) Auf dieser Seite werden aufgelistet:

- Nomen
- Artikel
- Adjektiv
- Pronomen
- Numerale
- Verb
- Adverb
- Präposition
- Konjunktion
- Interjektion

Aber diese Begriffe scheinen nicht klar definiert zu sein. Nomen sind Wörter, die dekliniert werden können, also Substantive, Adjektive und Pronomen. Wäre es daher nicht klüger, die Nomen aus der Liste zu streichen und durch Substantive zu ersetzen?

Ich habe auch diese Liste gefunden: [Wortarten auf Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hilfe:Wortart) Dort stehen, wenn ich richtig gezählt habe, 24 Wortarten, von denen die meisten noch in weitere Unterarten unterteilt sind.

Dann gibt es auch Artikelwörter, zu denen außer den Artikeln auch Zahlwörter, einige Pronomen, Fragewörter und noch ein paar andere Wörter gehören.

Und was ist mit Fragewörtern? Ist das nicht auch eine Wortart?

Wo gehören die Partizipien hin? Sind das einfach nur gebeugte Verben? Oder gehören die zu den Adjektiven? Denn sie werden ja wie Adjektive verwendet. ("der fahrende Bus, die gefahrene Strecke")

Was ist mit substantivierten Adjektiven und Verben? ("die Schöne, der Schlafende"). Sind das Substantive? Oder doch Adjektiven und Verben? Oder eine eigenständige Wortart? Denn die verhalten sich weder wie gewöhnliche Substantive (können jedes Geschlecht haben, werden auf ganz spezielle Weise gebeugt) noch wie Adjektiven und Verben (können Subjekt eines Satzes sein)

Gibt es eine klare und eindeutige Übersicht über alle deutschen Wortarten, sozusagen eine "offizielle" Liste?

Comment: Auch [grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/244), 11 Wortarten.

Comment: Hi Alina! Das ist eher eine Frage zur Grammatik-Theorie als zur Grammatik. Möglicherweise bist du damit bei https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/ damit besser aufgehoben. Die Antwort hängt davon ab, wie man "Wortart" definiert. Die Frage ist also eher: Welche unterschiedlichen Definitionen von "Wortart" sind gebräuchlich, werden diskutiert, sind sinnvoll? Du scheinst davon auszugehen, dass es eine feste, autoritative Definition dieses Begriffs gibt. Häufig haben Begriffe aber mehrere verschiedene Bedeutungen, je nach Kontext und Verwendungsabsicht.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach, was Du schreibst, ist definitiv hilfreicher als meine Antwort, aber ich wollte nicht wieder angepflaumt werden, nicht in einem Kommentar zu antworten. Vielleicht ist Dein Kommentar ein Schließgrund?

Comment: @CarstenS Das mit dem "Anpflaumen" tut mir leid, ich hoffe, das ging nicht von mir oder den anderen Mods aus. Oft ist es ein schmaler Grat. Wir sollten als Community darüber diskutieren können, aber Anpflaumen sollte in keinem Fall passieren. Zur Sache: Ich denke auch darüber nach, ob die Frage geschlossen werden sollte. Ich könnte mir aber auch eine Antwort vorstellen, die die falsche Prämisse der Frage aufklärt, und die gebräuchlichsten Theorien darstellt. Mit einer solchen Antwort wäre die Frage in meinen Augen ein Gewinn hier. Leider kann ich das selbst nicht leisten. Aber du vielleicht?

Comment: @JonathanScholbach, alles gut, warst nicht Du.  Und ich bin ganz sicher kein Grammatiker, ich weiß nicht einmal, ob die so heißen ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Das Verhältnis der Grammatik zur Sprache ist *post festum*. Das bedeutet, Sprache ist, was man spricht oder schreibt und und die Grammatik versucht lediglich im Nachhinein, das durch Regeln zu fassen. Das ist auch der Grund, warum es so viele Ausnahmen von den Regeln gibt - das widerspiegelt lediglich das Substrat dessen, was diese Regeln nicht erfassen (können).

Tatsächlich gibt es nicht "10 Arten von Wörtern" oder "11 Arten von Wörtern", sondern es gibt - Wörter. Wir können sie in verschiedene Gruppen einteilen und dann untersuchen, ob diese Gruppen gemeinsame oder abweichende Eigenschaften haben. Manchmal bringt eine solche Untersuchung verwertbare Erkenntnisse (zB können alle "Verben" "konjugiert" werden, Nomen/Substantiva nicht) und dann ist diese Einteilung nützlich. Wir könnten auch andere Einteilungen treffen ("alle Wörter die auf a (b, c, ...) enden"), die vielleicht weniger oder gar nicht nützlich sind. (Falls dir die vorgeschlagene Einteilung komplett unnütz vorkommt: stell dir ein Reimwörter-Lexikon vor, dann könnte eine Einteilung nach letzten Silben durchaus nützlich sein).

Letztlich sind aber alle diese Einteilungen nachträgliche Kategorisierungen für etwas, das schon vorher da war, nämlich die Wörter selbst. Das bedeutet im Umkehrschluß, daß wir alle diese Kategorisierungen gleichzeitig verwenden können, je nachdem, welche grade am meisten für unseren jeweiligen Zweck leistet.

Womit wir bei der Frage wären, was die vorgeschlagenen Einteilungen leisten und was für einen Erkenntnisgewinn wir aus ihnen ziehen können.

Zunächst der Link zur Tante Wiki: das ist eigentlich keine "Liste von Wortarten", sondern eine Hilfestellung, wie man bei Titeln von "Lemmata" (so heißen die Artikel in einem Lexikon) verfahren sollte. Letztlich will man nicht, daß der eine Artikel "Autos" (Plural) heißt, der andere aber "Fahrrad" (Singular), sondern entweder beides Singular oder beides Plural. Deshalb ist diese Liste auch nicht vollständig oder eine grammatikalisch verwertbare Einteilung - sie ist einfach *dafür* gar nicht gemacht.

Außerdem gibt es viele Arten von Wörtern, die im Deutschen nicht vorkommen, beispielsweise *Klitiken*. Das sind Wörter, die an andere drangehängt werden, aber nicht alleine auftreten, zum Beispiel das "-que" im Lateinischen, das soviel wie "und" bedeutet. *SPQR* - "Senatus Populus*que* Romanum" - "Senat und Volk von Rom".

> Und was ist mit Fragewörtern? Ist das nicht auch eine Wortart?

Die Antwort mag unbefriedigend sein, aber: ja, das ist eine Wortart, wenn die Einteilung, die Fragewörter in eine eigene Gruppe einsortiert, dir die Antwort auf eine Frage gibt, die dir eine andere Einteilung nicht geben könnte. Ähnliches gilt für jede andere Art der Einteilung auch. Die Frage ist nicht *ist das eine Gruppe*, sondern, *ist eine Einteilung in eine solche Gruppe für meinen Zweck sinnvoll*.

Ist es sinnvoll, substantivierte Adjektive zu den Substantiven zu zählen? Naja, wenn es um Deklination geht, vermutlich schon. Wenn es um was anderes geht, vielleicht auch, vielleicht aber auch nicht - das hängt davon ab, worum es eben geht.

PS: Mir ist durchaus bewußt, daß das wahrscheinlich nicht die Antwort ist, die Du Dir erhofft hast, denn letztlich habe ich Dir wortreich erklärt, daß die Frage falsch gestellt ist. Bessere ist allerdings - meines Wissens - keine vorrätig.

Comment: Kannst du eine Übersicht über die diskutierten Einteilungen geben, und ihre Fürs und Widers darstellen? Gegenwärtig ist deine Antwort eine Eindordung, Problematisierung oder gar Zurückweisung der Fragestellung. Das ist OK, weil die Frage in der Tat problematisch ist. Ich denke aber, dass eine Antwort wie beschrieben das der Frage zugrundeliegende Bedürfnis noch besser addressieren würde. Wenn du das leisten könntest, würde aus deiner richtigen Antwort eine exzellente.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Bittesehr! Ich hoffe, das entspricht dem, was Du Dir vorgestellt hast.

Comment: Es ist auf jeden Fall eine Verbesserung. Meine Traumvorstellung ist, dass es eine Antwort gibt, á la: "In der Grammatiktheorie des Deutschen sind die folgenden drei konkurrierenden Definitionen des Begriffs "Wortart" die bedeutendsten" und dann folgt eine kurze Diskussion der jeweiligen Vor- und Nachteile, bzw. Anwendungsbereiche der jweiligen Definition. Mittlerweile wüsste ich einfach gern die Antwort darauf, und zwar so sehr, dass ich würde ein Bounty von 500 Punkten dafür vergeben würde. :)

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: das kann ich verstehen, aber das geht über meine Kompetenz hinaus. Das überlasse ich gerne den promovierten Linguisten hier.

Comment: Das verstehe ich gut. Geht mir ganz genauso.

Answer (score 2):

#### Gibt es eine offizielle Liste?

Nein, die gibt es nicht. Generell kann man sagen, das nichts, was die *eigentliche* deutsche Sprache betrifft, offiziell geregelt ist. Das einzige, das einer offiziellen Regelung unterliegt (nämlich durch den [Rechtschreibrat](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com)) ist die Codierung der deutschen Sprache in Form von Schrift. Da geht es also nur darum, wie Sprache gespeichert und transportiert wird, nicht um das, was da in die Schriftform gebracht wird. Dazu zählt auch die Zeichensetzung.

Alles andere, also Wortschatz, Grammatik, Aussprache, also alles, was die eigentliche Sprache ausmacht, wird von keiner Institution reglementiert. Das einzige reglementierende »Gremium« ist die Gesamtheit aller Sprecher der deutschen Sprache.

Auch die Wörterliste des Rechtschreibrates ist keine offizielle Liste in dem Sinn, dass nur solche Wörter existieren würden, die in dieser Liste stehen. Die Liste ist nur dazu da, um die Rechtschreibung der wichtigsten deutschen Wörter zu definieren.

Und weil eine Liste der existierenden Wortarten nicht in das Tätigkeitsgebiet des Rechtschreibrates fällt, gibt es eine solche Liste nicht, jedenfalls nicht als offizielles Dokument.

Was es aber natürlich schon gibt, sind Leute, die erkennen, dass gewisse Wörter Ähnlichkeiten mit anderen haben, und dass es Sinn macht, Schubladen zu erfinden, in die man ähnliche Wörter stecken kann. Aber welche Schubladen (Kategorien) das genau sein sollen, ist nicht immer ganz eindeutig.

#### Was ist eine brauchbare Liste?

Das kommt darauf an, wofür du die Liste verwenden willst. In den meisten Fällen wird man mit den ca. 10 Wortarten, die du aufgelistet hast, sein auslangen finden. Wenn du es genauer brauchst, ist die von dir genannte Liste von Wiktionary sicher eine gute Hilfe. Aber man kann sogar diese recht detaillierte Liste noch weiter ausbauen. Dort git es nämlich z.B. den Eintrag »Verb«, der nicht weiter unterteilt ist. Tatsächlich gibt es aber Modalverben (sollen), Hilfsverben (haben) und Copula (bleiben) die sich grammatisch anders verhalten als die übrigen Verben. Dann gibt es Bewegungsverben (stellen) und Lageverben (stehen) die auch ihre Besonderheiten haben, usw.

#### Haben unterschiedliche Sprachen unterschiedliche Wortarten?

Das hast du zwar nicht explizit gefragt, aber da du mehrmals ausdrücklich die deutsche Sprache angeführt hast, und die Frage im Deutsch-Forum gestellt hast (und nicht im Linguistik-Forum, wie es in Kommentaren vorgeschlagen wurde), vermute ich, dass du davon ausgehst, dass es Unterschiede gibt. Außerdem wurde darüber in Kommentaren diskutiert, was ebenfalls rechtfertig, hier darauf einzugehen.

Ja, unterschiedliche Sprachen haben unterschiedliche Wortarten. Als Beispiel fallen mir die Modalpartikel ein, die im gesprochenen Deutsch einen erheblichen Anteil haben, aber es gibt diese Wortart nicht in Sprachen wie Englisch oder Französisch.

Besonders schwierig ist die Zuordnung von Wörtern zu Wortarten in agglutinierenden Sprachen wie z.B. Finnisch. Das Wort »taloissani« bedeutet »in meinen Häusern«. Es vereinigt also eine Präposition, ein Possessivpronomen und ein Substantiv in sich. Man könnte das Wort als Vereinigung von allen dreien ansehen, aber so etwas gibt es in flektierenden Sprachen wie Deutsch nicht. In dieser Hinsicht sind polysynthetische Sprachen wie z.B. Yupik (eine Eskimosprache) sogar noch schlimmer. Da werden mitunter recht viele Morpheme zu einem einzigen Wort zusammengefügt, für das man im Deutschen einen ganzen Satz sage müsste. Beispiel: »tuntussuqatarniksaitengqiggtuq« = »Er hat nicht nochmal gesagt, dass er Rentiere jagen geht.«

Comment: _just_, _already_, _yet_, _still_ und _even_ sind nur einige Modalpartikel im Englischen...

Comment: Oder etwas extremer _talossanikinpa_, z.B. "**Talossanikinpa** on kissa" heißt sowas wie "**Sogar auch in meinem Haus** ist eine Katze", mit den Segmenten "talo-ssa-ni-kin-pa"

Comment: Ja, Finnisch kann schon was (ich habe einen finnischen Arbeitskollegen): »kalsarikännit« = »sich allein daheim in Unterhosen besaufen«

Comment: Wobei da zuhause und alleine impliziert ist. Wörtlich bedeutet es nur "Unterhosensuff"